# Get numbers and words after determined word with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get numbers with words after a determined word with regex:

```
var text = 'SOME HUGE TEXT ARCHIVE: KxhASjx0000-4 SOME HUGH TEXT';
var reg   = new RegExp('ARCHIVE:' + '.*?(\\d\\S*)', 'i');
var match = reg.exec(text);
```

output will be:

```
0000-4
```

And i need:

```
KxhASjx0000-4
```

How can i improve this regex?

I was trying to use the `W` symbol, but didn't work:

```
.*?(\\d\w+\\S*)
```

Comment: Your string suggests that you're looking through a potentially enormous string, do you *really* want all 'numbers and words'? Or do you want a specific *pattern* of numbers and words following the specified word?

Comment: i want the next value of words and letters.

Comment: yes, it is a huge text from a pdf hahaha

Comment: So you need to match a specific pattern then? Or a range of patterns? Without that required information we can't really help except by guessing.

Comment: You are using the character set wrongly, check my answer for the correct implementation of your idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
var reg = new RegExp('ARCHIVE:' + '.*?([a-z\\d]\\S*)', 'i');
```

Or better:

```
var reg = /ARCHIVE:.*?([a-z\d]\S*)/i;
```

Instead of matching till a digit `\d` here we're matching upto `[a-z\d]` which is a letter or a digit that gives us match `KxhASjx0000-4` in matched group.

**Output:**

```
var match = reg.exec(text);
// ["ARCHIVE: KxhASjx0000-4", "KxhASjx0000-4"]
```

Comment: ok I wrote an explanation in answer. @DavidThomas: Thanks for your comment, I always take any critique in right sprit but I beg to differ with *you almost never explain your answers*. But I agree there have been instances like this answer when OP already had written a pretty good regex and needs a minor tweak to fix the regex.

Comment: The quantifier of 'almost never' is filtered heavily by the few answers of yours that I see, which tends to be in both a relatively limited section of the day; and I'm not a huge fan of - or particularly gifted with - regular expression, so I'm assuming I don't participate in the same tags as you very often. My apologies for any offence I've caused, and my genuine thanks for your courtesy.

Comment: Sorry @anubhava, i was thinking that i already accept your answer. Could you give me a hand in find the last reference if there is more than one  ARCHIVE?

Comment: NP at all, let me address this on other thread since you have placed an example input that I can work on.

Comment: You can use: `/IDENTIFIER(?!.*IDENTIFIER).*?(\d\S*)/i.exec(text);`

Comment: There are differences between new RegExp and // ?

Comment: cant be usable as new RegExp('IDENTIFIER(?!.*IDENTIFIER).*?(\d\S*)', 'i'); ?

Comment: It can be: `new RegExp('IDENTIFIER(?!.*IDENTIFIER).*?(\\d\\S*)', 'i');`

Comment: this is madness... i cant understand that, i already study the signs but the logic behind is very difficult to understand ://.. I hate coming here every time for help on regular expressions , I feel so frustrated.. :/

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html is pretty good tutorial on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this if you know that "ARCHIVE" is there in all of the lines :

```
.*?ARCHIVE:\s?([\w ]+\s?\S*)
```

It checks for ARCHIVE: and then white space if any, then it reads the word associated with and another white space if any. After that it reads the required digit.

> --> .*? - Any character any number of times
>   -->ARCHIVE:
>
>   --> s? - white space if any -->A numbered captured group -->[\w ]+ - any character in this class.  --> \S* - anything other than white space.

PS: Do not forget to escape the characters accordingly.